# Delete facebook post from page

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Am working on a facebook application to post images to a page, i want to delete a particular the facebook post using javascript api, any help please?

This is my code:

```
FB.api('/1234/photos', 'post', {
      access_token : FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'],
      message: "message",
            url   : '',
            from   : 1234,
    }, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
```

Delete post function:

```
function delete_post(post_id)
{
    FB.api(post_id, 'delete',function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
        alert('Post was deleted');
        }
    });
}
```

This is not working for me, always getting error occured message.
which Id should i choose to delete a post? response.id or response.post_id?

Thanks

Comment: Log the response object to console to see what the error actually is …

Comment: am getting the error like : Object {error: Object}
error: Object
message: "unknown error"
type: "http"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: Actually i want to delete the post from a page..is it possible?Facebook API is providing examples to delete a post only, how can i delete a post from a page?i have searched a lot , but am not getting any results..